# get JavaScript table values to c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a website in asp.net c# and I've auto-generated a table in JavaScript. How can I get the values of the rows to c#?

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5owb3rhL/

This is my code for asp (I've changed it to html for simplicity)

```
<select id="select" multiple style="width: 100px;">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
              </select>

              <table>
                <tbody id="target">
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

This is the javascript

```
<script>

function generateRows(items, targetName) {  
  let target = document.querySelector(targetName);
  // clear the rows
  target.innerHTML = '';

  let rows = '';
  for(let i = 0; i <items.length; i++) {
     rows += `<tr><td>${items[i]}</td><td> <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange"><p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p></td></tr>`;
  }

  // append once
  target.innerHTML = rows;
}
function mainGenerator(classNames, targetName) {  
document.querySelector(classNames).onchange = function (e) {
    let items = [];
    for (var i= 0; i < e.currentTarget.options.length; i++) {
    let opt = e.currentTarget.options[i];

    if (opt.selected) {
      items.push(opt.value);
    }
  }

  // pass the selected items to function to generate the rows
  generateRows(items, targetName);
};
}

mainGenerator('#select', '#target');

</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript is one word, with a capital S.

Comment: If this is ASP.NET Web Forms, you would need to do some sort of postback in order for your codebehind to get the data.

Comment: what do you want to commit to server? the sample code is messive, can you clean/format and give a new example?

Comment: I want to commit the rows in the table tbody id=target.

Comment: Is this for Web Forms or MVC?

You'll either need to do a form submit with the values or send the data via AJAX with javascript.